# How to access batch file that I saved as a resource?

Tags: c#

I saved some batch file as a resource on my application. 
I want to access this file on run time - so I trying to file this file on the Resource folder but I get an exception that the

> "resource folder is not there"

I trying to find the resource file by this code

```
var allBatchFiles = Directory.GetFiles( string.Format( @"..\..\Resources\" ) );
```

So how to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two types of resources you might be referring to.

First, if you are referring to a RESX file, then usually you can access resources directly.  So if you have a RESX file called "MyRes.resx" with a resource in it called "MyString" then you can use:

```
string contents = Resources.MyRes.MyString;
```

If you are adding files to the solution and marking them as Embedded Resources, then you can use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to access the data.  Here's the utility functions I use:

```
public static Stream GetResourceStream(string pathName, string resName, Assembly srcAssembly = null)
{
    if (srcAssembly == null) srcAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var allNames = srcAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    return srcAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(pathName + "." + resName);
}
public static string GetResourceString(string pathName, string resName, Assembly srcAssembly = null)
{
    if (srcAssembly == null) srcAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GetResourceStream(pathName, resName, srcAssembly));
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    return s;
}
```

The `pathName` is a bit tricky - it's the name of the project plus any folder names in your project.  So if you have a project "MyApp" with a folder called "MyResources" with a file called "Batch.txt" marked as a resource, then you would access the contents with:

```
string contents = GetResourceString("MyApp.MyResources", "Batch.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that, when you run your application in Visual Studio, it is executed from the `bin` subfolder, which changes relative paths.

However, if you want to *embed* the batch file into your application, you are entirely on the wrong track. The resource is compiled into your `EXE`, and you need to use a different method to retrieve it. The following MSDN article gives an example on how this can be done:

- [How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292/en-us)